# equivalent to windows forms application in visual studio for mac?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-mac

I'm self taught so my main reason for asking this question is because I am learning C# from books (C# 5.0 for dummies & Headfirst C#) and both of them teach C# using visual studio for windows. My computer is a mac so I downloaded Visual Studio for mac but...

I'm not sure what the equivalent would be for a windows forms application.

So if anyone knows which type of project is similar enough for me to use it when trying out the code I am learning through these books I would appreciate your help or advice!

Comment: That would be Xamarin Forms.

Comment: In terms  of GUI : `Xamarin.Mac` (which could be used to produce a macOS Cocoa "native" application) or `Xamarin.Forms` if you are looking for a cross-platform solution.

Comment: Or you setup a Windows - VM, but I guess you want to write for Mac later on, right?

Comment: Windows Forms is tie to Win32 API so you want to check Mono : https://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/winforms/. WinForms might not be the best way to learn C# on a Mac. Maybe .NET Core?